# list manipulation with minimal iteration

Tags: python, list, iteration

lets say that you have the following two lists:

```
l1 = [0,30,45,55,80,90]
l2 = [35,65,70,75,100,120]
```

**rules for the lists:**

1. `l1` always starts at 0 and `l2` must start at greater than 0 both
2. lists must be in order from smallest to biggest

**the goal:**

essentially each number is an index for opening and closing of something. The goal is to return the item in `l2` that closes the first item in `l1`

**explanation:**

an item in `l2` will "close" the item in `l1` that is the closest number smaller than itself. then both of those numbers are no longer usable. Using the lists given as examples, this is what would happen:

0 opens

30 opens

35 closes 30

45 opens

55 opens

65 closes 55

70 closes 45

75 closes 0

**answer = 75**

I believe there is a way to do this with only iterating through each list once. The way that I have come up with, requires iterating through `l1` as many times as things are closed. So in this example, it must iterate 4 times to get the right answer. Here is that function:

```
def f(l1,l2):
    for x in l2:
        new_l = [i for i in l1 if i < x]
        closed = new_l[-1]
        if closed == 0:
            answer = x
            break
        else:
            l1.remove(closed)
    return answer
```

Is there any way to detect what closes what so that I do not need to iterate as many times as necessary. In my actual situation this could require hundreds of iterations because this function will actually be run in a loop that could go for a while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `bisect` module:

```
import bisect
def f(l1,l2):
    for x in l2:
        ind = bisect.bisect(l1,x)
        # if the index where the item from l2 can fit in l1 is 1,
        # then it's time to return 
        if ind - 1 == 0:           
            return x
        del l1[ind-1]   #otherwise remove the item from l1


l1 = [0,30,45,55,80,90]
l2 = [35,65,70,75,100,120]
print f(l1,l2)
#75
```

Comment: THIS IS PERFECT!!! Just so I undestand before I accept...this will find the place where each item in the second list would go, and then remove the item before it? therefore it does not have to iterate through the first list at all

Comment: @RyanSaxe yes exactly, It does iterates over `l1` but using binary search which is an `O(Log N)` operation compared to linear search's `O(N)`.

Comment: @RyanSaxe: This can require O(Nlog(N)) time for binary searches and O(N^2) time for deletions, though. There's an O(N) algorithm, but it's a bit messier.

Comment: Also, it modifies `l1`, which is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @user2357112 I'd love to see your `O(N)` algo, :)

Comment: l1 is continually redefined in my actual situation, so that part does not matter. What would be the O(N) algorithm?

Comment: ...and it looks like someone else beat me to it by a few seconds. Less explanation in their post, though.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a variation of a standard parenthesis matching problem. The primary difference is that instead of a single sequence of openers and closers, the openers and closers are numbered, and their order is defined by their numbers. We can lazily merge them into a single sequence, then go through the sequence and keep a count of unclosed openers until we find the closer for the first opener. This runs in O(n), where n is the index of the closer for the first opener.

```
def merge_iterator(openers, closers):
    """Goes through the openers and closers, merging the sequences.

    Yields (opener, 1) or (closer, -1) tuples, sorted by the values of the
    openers or closers. Each yield runs in O(1).

    """
    openers = iter(openers)
    closers = iter(closers)
    opener = next(openers)
    closer = next(closers)
    try:
        while True:
            if opener < closer:
                yield opener, 1
                opener = next(openers)
            else:
                yield closer, -1
                closer = next(closers)
    except StopIteration:
        # Ran out of openers. (We can't run out of closers first.)
        yield closer, -1
        for closer in closers:
            yield closer, -1

def find_closer(openers, closers):
    merged_sequence = merge_iterator(openers, closers)

    # open the first opener
    unclosed = 1
    next(merged_sequence)

    # open and close openers until the first opener closes
    for item, change_in_unclosed in merged_sequence:
        unclosed += change_in_unclosed
        if not unclosed:
            # We closed the first opener. Return the closer.
            return item
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you

```
def findBiggest(L, val):
    """ Basically a modified binary search """
    if len(L) == 1:
        return L[0]
    elif L[len(L)/2] >= val:
        return biggest(L[:len(L)/2], val)
    else:
        return findBiggest(L[len(L)/2:], val)

def findOpens(opens, closes):
    for c in closes:
        opener = findBiggest(opens, c)
        opens.remove(opener)
        if opener == 0:
            print 'answer =', c
            return opener
```

Answer (score 0):

This should the trick in `O(N)`.

```
 def find_answer(l1, l2):
    opened = 0
    curr_l2 = 0

    for el in l1:
        if el > l2[curr_l2]:
            while curr_l2 < len(l2) and el > l2[curr_l2]:
                if opened == 1:
                    return l2[curr_l2]
                elif opened > 1:
                    # l2[curr_l2] closes an element.
                    opened -= 1
                    curr_l2 += 1
                else:
                    # Noone left to close
                    return None
        # `el` opens
        opened += 1
   # Remaining elements to close left
   return None
```